# overriding +[groupTableViewBackgroundColor] via category on UIColor

Tags: iphone, overriding

How do I override using a `category`? So if I have:

```
#import "UIColor+backColor.h"
@implementation UIColor (backColor)
@end
```

What do I add to override `+[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply re-implement it:

```
+ (UIColor *)groupTableViewBackgroundColor {
    return mySpecialColor;
}
```

It'll be overridden when you do this.

Edit: this didn't appear to have been working (although it should have done so!), so here's a really barebones method swizzling implementation for changing the return value of the method:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

UIColor *modified(Class __self, SEL __cmd)
{
    return someOtherColor;
}

Class clazz = [UIColor class];
static IMP original;
Method m = class_getClassMethod(clazz, @selector(groupTableViewBackgroundColor));
original = method_setImplementation(m, (IMP)modified);
```

This all should be done early during initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much. They would I do:

Comment: tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]; - but that just returns the default background color.

Comment: If this doesn't work (despite it should), you can use method swizzling to change the implementation of this particular method.